# goose-extractor for python 3.4 Error

Tags: python, django

Tried `pip3 install goose-extractor`

Error message getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-kiim5udg/beautifulsoup/setup.py", line 22
        print "Unit tests have failed!"
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-kiim5udg/beautifulsoup/
```

Is there  python 3.4 version exists?
Any other similar package?

Answer (score 2):

[`goose-extractor`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/goose-extractor/) currently supports just python 2.7 and earlier versions.

With python 3 you can use the [`readability-lxml`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/readability-lxml) package, which has a pretty similar feature set as goose.

Comment: How can i extract images from an html using readability.If i may?

Comment: You can do that with BeautifulSoup which is being installed alongside readability: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 0):

the current version of [goose-extractor](https://github.com/grangier/python-goose) is 1.0.25, in which the requirements contains beautifulsoup 3.2.1, but this bs package is based on python2.x, so u got the error :Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

Answer (score 0):

install goose 3 version for python 3

```
 pip install goose3==3.1.6
```

Link to PyPi:
[goose 3](https://pypi.org/project/goose3/3.1.6/)